# Mysterious Feb 10th 2012 not setting to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

First the data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calendar_events` (
`event_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
`event_day_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
`event_year` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`event_time` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`event_time_to` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`event_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`event_desc` text NOT NULL,
`event_type` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `calendar_events`
--

INSERT INTO `calendar_events` (`event_id`, `event_day`, `event_day_to`,    `event_year`, `event_time`, `event_time_to`, `event_title`, `event_desc`, `event_type`) 
VALUES
(8, '2012-02-10', '2012-02-10', 0, '', NULL, 'Feb 10', '', NULL),
(5, '2012-02-21', '2012-02-23', 0, '', NULL, '21-23 range addition', '', NULL),
(4, '2012-02-15', '2012-02-18', 0, '', NULL, 'Febbb 18', 'Some stuff here as a description', NULL),
(7, '2012-02-12', '2012-02-12', 0, '', NULL, 'single date 12', '', NULL),
(9, '2012-02-28', '2012-02-28', 0, '', NULL, 'test 28Date', '', NULL),
(10, '2012-02-01', '2012-02-01', 0, '', NULL, 'feb1', '', NULL);
```

Query that makes the values available:

```
mysql_select_db($database_MySQLconn, $MySQLconn);
$query_rsDates = "SELECT calendar_events.event_day, calendar_events.event_id, calendar_events.event_title, calendar_events.event_desc, calendar_events.event_day_to FROM calendar_events";
$rsDates = mysql_query($query_rsDates, $MySQLconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates);
$totalRows_rsDates = mysql_num_rows($rsDates);
```

Next the code setting the values to an array:

```
$dates = array();


while ($row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates))
{

for($start_date = strtotime($row_rsDates['event_day']);
$start_date <= strtotime($row_rsDates['event_day_to']);
$start_date = $start_date + 24*3600)

{
$row_rsDates['event_day'] = date("Y-n-j", $start_date);
$dates[] = $row_rsDates;
}
}

echo json_encode($dates);
```

Resulting JSON:

```
[{"event_day":"2012-2-21","event_id":"5","event_title":"21-23 range addition","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-23"},{"event_day":"2012-2-22","event_id":"5","event_title":"21-23 range addition","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-23"},{"event_day":"2012-2-23","event_id":"5","event_title":"21-23 range addition","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-23"},{"event_day":"2012-2-15","event_id":"4","event_title":"Febbb 18","event_desc":"Some stuff here as a description","event_day_to":"2012-02-18"},{"event_day":"2012-2-16","event_id":"4","event_title":"Febbb 18","event_desc":"Some stuff here as a description","event_day_to":"2012-02-18"},{"event_day":"2012-2-17","event_id":"4","event_title":"Febbb 18","event_desc":"Some stuff here as a description","event_day_to":"2012-02-18"},{"event_day":"2012-2-18","event_id":"4","event_title":"Febbb 18","event_desc":"Some stuff here as a description","event_day_to":"2012-02-18"},{"event_day":"2012-2-12","event_id":"7","event_title":"single date 12","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-12"},{"event_day":"2012-2-28","event_id":"9","event_title":"test 28Date","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-28"},{"event_day":"2012-2-1","event_id":"10","event_title":"feb1","event_desc":"","event_day_to":"2012-02-01"}]
```

The 10th of Feb does not show…
I can add a new single date (same start and end date) and these work perfectly. I can remove the 10th of Feb and reinsert it as a new record but it still fails to show…

Now let’s print_r the current array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-21
[event_id] => 5
[event_title] => 21-23 range addition
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-23
)

[1] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-22
[event_id] => 5
[event_title] => 21-23 range addition
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-23
)

[2] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-23
[event_id] => 5
[event_title] => 21-23 range addition
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-23
)

[3] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-15
[event_id] => 4
[event_title] => Febbb 18
[event_desc] => Some stuff here as a description
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-18
)

[4] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-16
[event_id] => 4
[event_title] => Febbb 18
[event_desc] => Some stuff here as a description
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-18
)

[5] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-17
[event_id] => 4
[event_title] => Febbb 18
[event_desc] => Some stuff here as a description
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-18
)

[6] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-18
[event_id] => 4
[event_title] => Feb 18 single date
[event_desc] => Some stuff here as a description
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-18
)

[7] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-12
[event_id] => 7
[event_title] => single date 12
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-12
)

[8] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-28
[event_id] => 9
[event_title] => test 28Date
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-28
)

[9] => Array
(
[event_day] => 2012-2-1
[event_id] => 10
[event_title] => feb1
[event_desc] =>
[event_day_to] => 2012-02-01
)

)
```

The mysterious 10th of Feb is nowhere to be found…

Why would this one date not work as the others? There is other single date events such as Feb 1st through Feb 1st so that is not the problem. And, if the Feb 10th date is added again as a second record (new event_id of course) this new record is added to the array without issue.

Why will the first record containing Feb 10th not be processed to the array?

Comment: You left out the actual SQL query for fetching the dates. Could you add the code for that (ie the mysql_query call?)

Comment: What does your query look like? Have you verified that it's actually returning that row? As ugly as your code is, there's no reason it should just skip a row for now reason.

Comment: Query added above and yes the value for the missing Feb 10 record is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling

```
$row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates);
```

before the while loop, you remove the first row. Just drop that line and things will be ok.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this when I tried to print_r the initial recordset and saw it grabbed the first record...Feb 10th...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple,
based on your code,
you have called mysql_fetch_assoc twice, and the result cursor (after the first call) is advanced to second row, thus the second call is start from second row onward, and thus the $date does not contains value from first record

1. `$row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates);`
2. `while ($row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates))`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling mysql_fetch_assoc once before the while loop. So the recordset you will find here won't contain the first result. The one with date 2012-02-10. So you should eliminate/comment the lines:

$row_rsDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDates);

$totalRows_rsDates = mysql_num_rows($rsDates);